# What changes in parameters should make when import StratifiedShuffleSplit from sklearn.model_selection by replacing sklearn.cross_validation

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was trying to run a python3 code for isolated speech recognition, there I got a DeprecationWarning for using:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit
```

In order to remove this warning, I just imported `StratifiedShuffleSplit` from `sklearn.model_selection` instead of `sklearn.cross_validation` and after running the code, I got:

> TypeError: 'StratifiedShuffleSplit' object is not iterable

Maybe because in

```
class sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, n_iter=10, test_size=0.1, train_size=None, random_state=None)
```

`y` is an array.

While in:

```
class sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, n_iter=10, test_size=0.1, train_size=None, random_state=None)
```

There is no array:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(all_labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

for n,i in enumerate(all_obs):
    all_obs[n] /= all_obs[n].sum(axis=0)

for train_index, test_index in sss:
    X_train, X_test = all_obs[train_index, ...], all_obs[test_index, ...]
    y_train, y_test = all_labels[train_index], all_labels[test_index]
ys = set(all_labels)
ms = [gmmhmm(7) for y in ys]
```

How to replace `all_labels` because it is an array according to `sklearn.cross_validation` but `sklearn.model_selection` don't accept an array parameter.

Comment: Please use bold wisely, and certainly not instead of code blocks...

Comment: I kindly suggest you keep history & verbal speculation to an absolute meaning, and post a [MCVE] with the full error trace (as is, it is not clear *where exactly* your error pops up); be sure to also remove whatever code may come *after* the error, since it is never executed and is irrelevant to the issue. Before anything, be sure to [**read the docs**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is that

- `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit` is a cross-validator
- `sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit` is a cross-validator **iterator**

Hence the correct usages from your example would be

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

for n,i in enumerate(all_obs):
    all_obs[n] /= all_obs[n].sum(axis=0)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(all_obs, all_labels):
     print(train_index, test_index)
```

It might be helpful to read the example in the docs of [sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)